# The program doesn't work correctly when I toggle the pin via Set and Reset register

Tags: c, gpio, stm32f10x

I have two program to do the same task. the both should toggle `GPIOB0`. the first program is this:

```
#include "stm32f10x.h"


/* Private functions ---------------------------------------------------------*/

GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStructure;


void GPIO_Configuration(void);


int main(void)
{
    GPIO_Configuration();

    GPIOB->ODR ^= GPIO_Pin_0;
    GPIOB->ODR ^= GPIO_Pin_0;
    GPIOB->ODR ^= GPIO_Pin_0;
    GPIOB->ODR ^= GPIO_Pin_0;
    GPIOB->ODR ^= GPIO_Pin_0;
    GPIOB->ODR ^= GPIO_Pin_0;
    GPIOB->ODR ^= GPIO_Pin_0;
    GPIOB->ODR ^= GPIO_Pin_0;
    GPIOB->ODR ^= GPIO_Pin_0;
    GPIOB->ODR ^= GPIO_Pin_0;

    /* Infinite loop */
    while (1)
    {

  }
}

/*******************************************************************************
* Function Name  : GPIO_Configuration
* Description    : Configure GPIO Pin
* Input          : None
* Output         : None
* Return         : None
* Attention      : None
*******************************************************************************/
void GPIO_Configuration(void)
{
  RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd( RCC_APB2Periph_GPIOB , ENABLE);                        
/**
 *  LED1 -> PB0
 */                  
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_0;
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_50MHz;
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_Out_PP; 
  GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStructure);


}
```

And the output:

[image: figure1]

Ok, five pulse as I expected. another program is this:

```
#include "stm32f10x.h"


/* Private functions ---------------------------------------------------------*/

GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStructure;


void GPIO_Configuration(void);


int main(void)
{
    GPIO_Configuration();

    GPIOB->BSRR = GPIO_Pin_0;
    GPIOB->BRR  = GPIO_Pin_0;
    GPIOB->BSRR = GPIO_Pin_0;
    GPIOB->BRR  = GPIO_Pin_0;
    GPIOB->BSRR = GPIO_Pin_0;
    GPIOB->BRR  = GPIO_Pin_0;
    GPIOB->BSRR = GPIO_Pin_0;
    GPIOB->BRR  = GPIO_Pin_0;
    GPIOB->BSRR = GPIO_Pin_0;
    GPIOB->BRR  = GPIO_Pin_0;

    /* Infinite loop */
    while (1)
    {

  }
}

/*******************************************************************************
* Function Name  : GPIO_Configuration
* Description    : Configure GPIO Pin
* Input          : None
* Output         : None
* Return         : None
* Attention      : None
*******************************************************************************/
void GPIO_Configuration(void)
{
  RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd( RCC_APB2Periph_GPIOB , ENABLE);                        
/**
 *  LED1 -> PB0
 */                  
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_0;
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_50MHz;
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_Out_PP; 
  GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStructure);


}
```

And output:

[image: figure2]

As you can see, there is just one pulse. Why? looks like it cannot make four next pulse. but why?

**Edit1:** the MCU is [STM32F103RET6](http://www.st.com/web/en/resource/technical/document/reference_manual/CD00171190.pdf).

**Edit2:** all explanations you can see in the reference manual for these three registers:

[image: figure3]

Comment: You will have to explain what is the difference of the ODR, BSRR and BRR used in the GPIO->xxx expressions.

Comment: @MichaelKaras Alright, done. look at the question again. and also those expressions are just a stracture(pointer) for putting the desired value to assigned register.

Answer (score 1):

Your second example will generate a *much* higher frequency than the first, possibly higer than the 16 MHz of you logic probe.

The first example has to use a read-modify-write cycle for each pin toggle, which requires at least 3 instructions to execute.

The second example only needs a single write instruction for each set/reset, resulting in a 36 MHz pin toggle frequency for a 72 MHz MCU.

Comment: Thanks TurboJ but are you sure? look at the both logic analyzer result. especially second example. you can see a pulse with the same frequency(look at the duty cycle of each pulse when pin is set(high)).

Comment: Use an oscilloscope with >50MHz Bandwidth to look at this signal. The digital inputs of a logic probe just won't tell you the whole story here, especially if there is something else wired to that pin that works as a capacity.

Comment: The speed difference is probably even greater than you describe because of pipelining and scheduling.  Neither loads nor stores occur in a single cycle, but I think a store can be started in the cycle immediately following another store so that a sequence of stores will be performed at a rate of one cycle each.